# Bash script shows changes in console but not in file | How do i save changes?

Tags: bash, tac

New to Bash scripting.

I have a textfile bar.txt with text:

```
123
456
789
```

I am trying to reverse this to:

```
987
654
321
```

I have managed to do this just fine with:

```
tac bar.txt | rev
```

However, the changes doesn't save to the .txt file, which still has 1234...

How do i save the changes, so that the .txt file is updated?
Sorry for badly phrased question or bad formatting - new to both Bash scripting and stackoverflow...

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True to the Unix philosophy of using shell utilities as filters operating on text, both `tac` and `rev` are piping their output to standard output, which is how `rev` is able to operate on the output from `tac`.

To "update the file," you can redirect the resulting output from `rev` to another file, like this.

```
tac bar.txt | rev > foo.txt
```

The reason you don't want to redirect the output to the same file is because Unix pipes operate on inputs as they are ready, so `foo.txt` will likely not have been completely read by the time the output from `rev` is ready to be written to the file.

You could just *append* the output, of course, like this:

```
tac bar.txt | rev >> foo.txt
```

This would **append** the output, though, not actually "update" the file.

If you wanted to actually "update the file", you could write a script that processed your input, piped it to a temporary file, and then replaced the original file with the new file using something like the `mv -f` command.

The reason I keep using the phrase "update the file" in quotation marks is because this process of creating a temporary file or memory buffer with the updated contents of the file that then replace the original file is usually what is happening when you "update a file." If you've ever seen the temporary files with the `~` symbol that vim creates, that's the temporary buffer that you're editing before the original file gets replaced, or as most people call it, "gets updated."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with

```
tac bar.txt | rev > bar_rev.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it appear as the file `bar` was changed, write the output first to a temp file - `foo` below - and `mv` it to `bar` after.

```
$ tac bar | rev > foo && mv foo bar
$ cat bar
987
654
321
```